# transfer the data in function which itself is parameter of other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

Tell me PLZ as it is possible correctly to transfer the data in function which itself is parameter of other function?

For example:

```
$('#my_element1').on('click', function(param){
    // use param = parameter #1
});

$('#my_element2').on('click', function(param){
    // use param = parameter #2
});
```

or

```
MyMegaFunc(func(param1));
MyMegaFunc(func(param2));
```

But the method

```
MyMegaFunc(func, param1);
MyMegaFunc(func, param2);
```

is not quite suitable, as it seems to me

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question? No head nor tail can be found on the current form.

Comment: do you want pass param to other function?

Comment: Shirish Patel, Yes, I want to pass function A (function with parameters) to function B and the parameters of the function A, but at the same time so that the parameters of the function A are not passed by a separate parameters

I want g(f(a)), but not g(f, a)

maybe factory?